# I'm having problems with the react-native-maps ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ref, react-native-maps

I'm using a functionalComponente and using useRef in the MapView component. But the functions are not coming through the ref, does anyone know how to correct?

code example

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'       //version 16.13.1
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'   //version 0.27.1
import {View} from 'react-native'         //version 0.63.2
    
    const Map = () => {
    
        const mapRef = useRef(null);
    
        return (
           <View>
             <MapView ref={mapRef}/>
           </View>
        )
    }
```

When I try to access mapRef.current, fitToCoodinates, getCamera, animateToRegion, etc ... are undefined. But I can get the props from mapRef.current.
Can someone help me? I want the functions, not the properties.

Comment: How/where are you calling the functions? Because I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: I'm trying mapRef.current.fitToCoordinates()

Comment: I am facing same issue